# Find the maximum of $2xy^2 - 2x^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

I got the constraint $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ (since the domain is $x^2+y^2\ge 1$ and $x\ge 0$) (it is a half circle domain) and the function $f(x,y)=2xy^2-2x^2$. I got the critical point to be $(0,0)$. The Hesse gave me $0$ which is of course no conclusion. I have a problem expressing $x$ and $y$ in terms of $\lambda$ but here is where my problem occurs. I get $\lambda=y^2-2$ and $\lambda=-y^2-2$. What am I doing wrong, is it the start?

Answer (score 1):

Before we start using Lagrange multipliers, lets look at the objective function.

$f(x,y) = x^2y - 2x^2$

If we set $y$ equal to zero, we can make $x$ large and get a very negative value for $f(x).$

If we set $x$ equal to something moderately small, say 1, and let $y$ become large, we get a very large positive value for $f(x).$  The function is unbounded in both directions within the limits of the constraint.

There is no absolute minimum or maximum.

We can use the method of Lagrange multipliers, to find critical points on the boundary of the constraint.

The constraints $x^2 + y^2 \ge 1$ and $x\ge 0$ give a half-plane, excluding a half-disk.

I am inclined to ignore the constraint $x\ge 0$ for the moment.

$F(x,y,\lambda) = 2xy^2 - 2x^2 + \lambda (x^2 + y^2 - 1)$

$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x} = 2y^2 - 4x + 2\lambda x  = 0\\
\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} = 4xy + 2\lambda y = 0\\
\frac {\partial f}{\partial \lambda} = x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$

from the second line:

$2\lambda y = -4xy$

Either $y = 0$ or $\lambda = -2x$

$y=0$ gives us $(1,0)$ as a critical point.

Setting $\lambda = -2x$ in the first line:

$2y^2 - 4x - 4x^2 = 0\\
y^2 = 2x^2 + 2x$

Substituting into the equation of the circle:
$3x^2 + 2x - 1 = 0\\
(3x - 1)(x+1)\\
x = \frac 13, -1$

$x = \frac 13$

$(\frac 13 , \pm \frac {\sqrt 8}{3})$ is a second set of critical points to check.

Answer (score 0):

$f_x=2y^2-4x,f_y=4xy$ so $2y^2-4x=2\lambda x$ and $4xy=2\lambda y$. The Lagrange condition in 2D is usually handled most easily by dividing one equation by the other to eliminate $\lambda$. In this case you then obtain $\frac{y}{2x}-\frac{1}{y}=\frac{x}{y}$. Clearing denominators you get $y^2/2 - x = x^2$. That in combination with the constraint $x^2+y^2=1$ is enough to find some points of interest, I think.

However this division is not in general legitimate; you needed $4xy \neq 0$ and $2 \lambda y \neq 0$, so you needed none of $x$ or $y$ or $\lambda$ to be zero.

So you need to go back and check those cases. For $\lambda=0$ you get either $x$ or $y$ being zero. In the case $x=0$ you get $y=0$, which violates the constraint. In the case $y=0$ you get $-4x=2\lambda x$ so either $\lambda=-2$ (contradiction) or $x=0$ (violates the constraint). So $\lambda \neq 0$.

If $x=0$ then immediately $2y^2=0$ so $y=0$, again violating the constraint.

If $y=0$ then $-4x=2\lambda x$ so either $x=0$ (violating the constraint) or $\lambda=-2$. In the latter case $x$ can be anything and still satisfy the second equation, so by using the constraint you conclude that $(1,0)$ is another point of interest.

Comment: I  follow the idea but not how this is what we get in my case. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @mathstudent23 What's the disconnect between this and your case?

Comment: @mathstudent23 Actually I missed that there is a $\lambda=0$ point, so I fixed that now.

Comment: my apologies, badly worded by my part. How do you arrive at your result is what I meant.   But $y$ can be $0$ and $x$ can be $0$ as well so I am really thrown off now.

Comment: @mathstudent23 Yeah, I caught that and sorted it out in the second paragraph.

Comment: So what system of equation would I end up with in that case? As you see in my post I got some result but they are obviously wrong and I do not know how to continue.

Comment: @mathstudent23 I don't know how you got your system. The system should read $2y^2=2\lambda x,4xy=2\lambda y,x^2+y^2=r^2$.

Comment: I forgot a vital detail; the system constraint is in the domain $x^2+y^2>=1$ and therefore the system should be $x^2+y^2=1$ not any radius. But still, in that case, how did you get $2y^2$? Wouldn't it be $2y^2-4x$?

Comment: OK sure, so $r=1$, that's fine. But you're right, I made an error, let me see how that gets fixed.

Comment: It is kind of complicated for me with the go back and check part. I just thought I had to find λ and simply plug in and get values that I could plug into the function to see if they are min/max values..

Comment: @mathstudent23 You can go that way, but you encounter the same basic difficulty. In the $y$ equation if you want to solve for $\lambda$ then you have to divide by $y$, so you get either $y=0$ or $\lambda=2x$. When $y=0$ you can find $x$ from the constraint and now have to check whether the $x$ equation can be satisfied. When $\lambda=2x$ you get $2y^2-x=4x^2$ from the first equation which you can solve in combination with the constraint.

Comment: I saw this method https://ibb.co/QdHnZf4 . Wouldnt this direct method be easier and quicker in this case? I found the critical point to be (0,0) but how would one proceed from here

Comment: @mathstudent23 Possibly, depends on the problem. But that isn't Lagrange multipliers, which is what you asked about.

Comment: Yes it is not it is for this same problem. I just thought Lagrange would have been easier. This seems more reasonable, though. I do not have to use Lagrange so a direct method might be simpler?